# cellForRowAtIndexPath not getting called but numbersOfRowInSection is

Tags: ios, for-loop, uitableview

I have a `for loop` in my project like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        [array addObject:randomObject];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

I have my dataSource methods like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Count: %lu",(unsigned long)array.count);
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Reloading Data");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Random";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

But for some strange reason only `numberOfRowsInSection` is getting called and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not.

Also cellForRowAtIndexPath DOES get called in the last time of the loop(when x is = to 1)

Comment: calling reload data in for loop??

Comment: The first one produced 1 but the second is not getting called

Comment: Have you tried implementing `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and making sure it doesn't return 0?

Comment: Do you ever create an instance of the `array` ?

Comment: Yes `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns 1 and I did create an instance of `array`. Also for some reason cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called in the last time of the loop(When i = to 1)

Comment: add [self.tableView reloadData] out of the loop

Comment: @suhit Tried, does not work.

Comment: what is randomObject, check if it is nil

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, you shouldn't reload the table view with each iteration. You should reload outside the loop. I think Apple optimized the implementation so that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for each row only once for each iteration of the runloop

Comment: @suhit, if randomObject was nil, that would raise an exception

Comment: @AhmedMohammed You are right and randomObject is not nil but I created a new project and I tried reloadData in a for loop and it worked

Answer (score 4):

**the tableview only asks for cells when it updates its view hierarchy.** Not when reloading its data. That will only cause it to update its internal size information.

**Updating cells only happens when the runloop is pogressed.** When you are in a loop, the main thread is blocked and then runloop is not progressed.

Only after your loop the OS runs the runloop and the table calls for Cells.

Answer (score 2):

All the datasource methods are called on the same thread. By calling `reloadData` you start the "queue" of datasource methods, by calling it again you cancel the previous "queue". This mechanics protects datasource from being inconsistent as if you have the data changed (hence the next `reloadData` call), the first "queue" operations would have outdated state.